# unable to get inserted values in pdf

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, itext

I want to convert  aspx to PDF using Pechkin.  the  values which are inserted in textbox are not in pdf what should i do to get the inserted values in the pdf

My aspx page contains images, textboxes, labels.

```
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
        if (confirmValue == "Yes")
        {
            try
            {
                string html;


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbUrl.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("The URL is empty.");
                }

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    html = client.DownloadString(tbUrl.Text);
                }


                //Transform the HTML into PDF


                var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
                var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                        .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1.5)
                                        .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                        .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                        .SetCreateExternalLinks(true), html);


                //Return the PDF file

                Response.Clear();

                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=test.pdf; size={0}", pdf.Length));
                Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);

                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();



            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `Pdfizer`? Is it an unofficial wrapper around iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the page url to a URI before sending it to the converter.

change your erroneous line to:

```
htmlToPdf.Run(new Uri(sbHtml.ToString(), UriKind.Relative)));
```

you are sending the url as a plain string, which makes the converter think that its the HTML string, so when trying to convert it, it encountered an 'error' right at the beginning because its not a valid html string.

**UPDATE:**

if the above doesnt work, use an absolute path.

first, use `Server.MapPath` to map an absolute path to your page:

```
string absolutePagePath = Server.MapPath("Contractor1.aspx");
```

and then send this to the pdfizer:

```
htmlToPdf.Run(new Uri(absolutePagePath));
```

Comment: getting a error " This operation is not supported for a relative URI"

Comment: getting a error                                                    "Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2."                                                  i think it cannot read that % how to get read only body part

Comment: my aspx page first line  is                                             <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Das.Master" EnableEventValidation = "false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contractor1.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Mobily2.Contractor1" %>

Comment: in that case the page needs to be compiled before sending it to the pdfizer. which means that you need to provide an absolute path on your website, instead of use `server.mappath`, as server mppath returns absolute path on your pc.

Comment: In that case write the full path aka: "www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/contractor1.aspx"

Comment: i have got  another code which is converting the aspx page to pdf but unable to get the values in the textboxes in pdf

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Page `URL` instead of Html string..

**`sbHtml.Append("Contractor1.aspx");`**

you have to create html first and pass it to `sbHtml` string..

```
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
    string sPathToWritePdfTo = @"C:\new_pdf_name.pdf";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sbHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sbHtml.Append("Contractor1.aspx");  // you have to pass HTML string here
    using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(sPathToWritePdfTo, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdf = new Pdfizer.HtmlToPdfConverter();
        htmlToPdf.Open(stream);
        htmlToPdf.Run(sbHtml.ToString());//error
        htmlToPdf.AddChapter("Mobily");
        htmlToPdf.Close();
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "mobily.pdf"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(sPathToWritePdfTo);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: contractor1.aspx is a html form how to pass it to sbhtml.Append();

Comment: @AtifUrRahman you dont need to. all you need to do is tell the converter that you are passing a page url, and it will load it for you.

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass page url  sbHtml.Append()